# Find In File and get the file name

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.NET and I am having issues extracting the file name instead of the full path.

I tried using substring to parse out after "\" but cannot use it because of readOnlyCollectio(of String)

```
Private Sub FindInFiles_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles findInFiles.Click
    ' Retrieves the path of the path selected by user.
    Dim myDocumentsPath As String = tree.SelectedNode.FullPath
    ' Look for the string "Visual Basic" in all document files in this 
    ' directory tree, in case-insensitive mode.
    Dim files As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String) =
       My.Computer.FileSystem.FindInFiles(MyApp.LastPath, txtFindText.Text, True,
       FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories)
    ' Show all file names in a listbox.
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each file As String In files
        ListBox1.Items.Add(file)
```

Comment: [Path.GetFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.8) is your friend

Answer (score 2):

First you want to Import System

```
Imports System
```

You will want to use the

```
IO.Path.GetFileName()
```

or if you want the Filename without Extension you do

```
IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this method

```
Private Function GetFilesWithText(path As String,
                                  txtToFind As String) As List(Of String)

    Dim rv As New List(Of String)
    rv = My.Computer.FileSystem.FindInFiles(path,
                                               txtToFind,
                                               True,
                                               FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories).ToList()

    For x As Integer = 0 To rv.Count - 1
        rv(x) = IO.Path.GetFileName(rv(x))
        '  OR
        'rv(x) = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(rv(x))
    Next
    Return rv
End Function
```

to use it

```
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(GetFilesWithText(MyApp.LastPath, txtFindText.Text).ToArray)
```